# Formatting a large SD card is taking time. What happens if I pause it?

Tags: mac, disk-format, sd-card

A few days ago, I formatted an SD card with Mac OS Ventura to make it bootable. Then, I wanted to reverse this process and use the SD card for transferring files again. So, I followed the instructions here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/280650/456222

Now, this SD card is 512GB. The process is taking a long time, projected to take 1-2 days. What happens if I prematurely cancel it? Is there a way to pause and resume the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dd` command you copied from the linked answer fills the whole disk with random bytes, depending on the size of the disk this will take ages.

The command most likely is not needed in your case (it's actually not needed to solve the problem in the question it attempts to answer either), so you can just press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to stop it, start **Disk Utility**, select the disk and erase/partition it as needed.

PS: Finder may complain about the disk being unreadable after you stopped `dd`. This is to be expected and nothing to worry about.

Comment: I found formatting the disk as FAT made it work on Android, Windows and Mac.